# Converting string into decimal result in decimal.InvalidOperation

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

I receive some input from an external device (serial) and I'm trying to parse the values into decimals. But **only** on my **raspberry pi in docker** I receive **sometimes** the following error:

> File "/usr/bin/asmp/worker/parser.py", line 58, in parse_line_value
>
> > return Decimal(value_node)
>
> decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]

The exception occurs in the follow function (first return statement):

```
 def parse_line_value(self, key, value_node):
    """Interprets the value of the line"""
    value_node = value_node.replace("*kWh", "").replace("*kW", "")
    print("Parsing value ("+key+"):'"+value_node+"'")

    if key is not None and ("usage_" in key or "return_" in key):
        return Decimal(value_node)

    return value_node
```

The input which causes the crash is the following

```
key = return_total_normal
value = 000000.000*kWh
```

As you can see I put a print statement in the function just before converting the string into a decimal, the last few lines before the crash are:

```
Parsing value (usage_total_low):'000333.744'
Parsing value (return_total_low):'000000.000'
Parsing value (return_total_normal):'000000.000'
```

So as you can see the value for return_total_low is exactly the same as return_total_normal but that works just fine. Also this sometimes occurs, so in other occasions I have no error and it functions for 10 days in a row. (parsing that value every 10 seconds)

Any clue which can put me on the right track?

Comment: Your debugging is not correct. Your code works fine when fed with the inputs you listed. You can easily confirm this yourself even in Python's REPL if need be.  So, *sometimes* the value converted is not what you expected but something that cannot be parsed (try "00000q000*kWh" for instance).   In other words it seems your logfile can't be trusted, it is obviously missing the offending value somehow.   Is it not flushed correctly when the program crashes perhaps?

Comment: @IrmendeJong: Well I see what you mean, but what do you purpose than? I now just use a print statement which prints it back to the console. When I try it with a invalid value (for example the 0000q000*kwh you prupose, I still prints that value just before it crashes..

Comment: It may be useful to change the print statement to `print("Parsing value ("+key+"):"+repr(value_node))`, as that will conveniently un-escape any ordinarily invisible whitespace characters. Not that I expect that to be the problem specifically, but it doesn't hurt to eliminate the possibility. Let us know if you do this and it shows something unusual.

Comment: @Kevin: You are a hero: It now shows 000000\x00.000, no idea yet what that char means and How I get it

Comment: "\x00", also represented as "\0", is a [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). Sometimes it signals the end of a stream of data. I don't know what it might mean in this specific context, though.

Comment: Not sure either, Im decoding the string first: str(connection.readline().decode("utf-8")).strip(), mayby using the wrong encoding or something.. but cant find in the docs which encoding I should use.